# CRX remote access with full JCR 2.0 API support

Tags: java, rmi, jcr, crx

I need to access a CRX content repository remotely. This is currently done via RMI.

But there are some essential methods (like `JcrUtils.getWeakReferences(node)` for instance) which lead to an **UnsupportedRepositoryOperationException**.

How can I access the repository with the ability to use all methods from the JCR 2.0 API? (RMI is no must-have.)